# How to print several dashes using a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to make a code in which I want to print 10 dashes using js. But the problem is that my code is not using the loop. It prints dash just one time. Can anyone please help me? Here is All code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "_";

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += i;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not know why it is printing numbers.

Comment: extra steps.. just use `'_'.repeat(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concatenate the dash, rather than i, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "_";

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += "_";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or just use [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "_";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.repeat(10);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `i`: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {Your code comes here}`

Answer (score 0):

Initially you set `text` to `_`. But in the loop you're concatenating the *index* of the loop (`i`), in other words the numbers 0 to 4. Instead simply just set your initial variable to an empty string, and then add a new underscore in the loop to the `text` variable ten times.

```js
let text = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  text += '_';
}

console.log(text.length);

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your loop is only set to run **5** times, so I would start there by making it 10.

```js
const TEXT_TO_APPEND = "_";
const HOW_MANY_DASHES = 10;
let text = "";

for (let i = 0; i < HOW_MANY_DASHES; i++) {
  text += TEXT_TO_APPEND;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is using repeat.

This method constructs and returns the concatenated new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const text = "_";
const repeated = text.repeat(10)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = repeated;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it prints numbers because you display the variable named i and it is the iteration number, you can print more dashes as the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">_</p>

<script>
// no need to make a variable here
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   // just append the new text like this to the old text
   document.getElementById("demo").innerText += "_";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's printing numbers because you're concatenating i which is a number that you're using to iterate through your loop, to your variable text. In the code below, I modified the loop count to include the 0 through 10 you described in your question. You want to have each iteration add "_" to your variable on each iteration. Remember the loop will make changes only to what is within your brackets. Then you're calling the innerText or InnerHTML to show the result made in the loop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
var text = "";

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  text += "_"
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>


</body>
</html>
```